# Need help on passing API data into components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on a very simple Movie finder that will return the list of movies that include the name of the movie entered by the user. For now, I'm only trying to show the info on the screen.

I'm using React and I'm having a hard time to make it work. I have three components, my main App components, the movieView component that will show the list of results, and the movie component itself that will show the title, overview and homepage of the movie. I'm new to React so I'm trying to understand how to make it work. Below is my code for each component:

```
   **APP COMPONENT:** 
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import Axios from 'axios';
    import MovieView from './movieview';
    // import NewsView from './NewsView';

    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          queryMovie: '',
          results: [],
          newsdata:'',
          movieFound: false,
        };
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
        this.searchMovie = this.searchMovie.bind(this);
      }

      handleInputChange(event) {
        event.preventDefault()
        this.setState({
          [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
        });
        }

      searchMovie(event) {
        console.log(this.state.queryMovie)
        event.preventDefault()
        Axios
        .get(`/api?query=${this.state.queryMovie}`)
        .then(results => results.data)
        .then(results => this.setState({ 
          results: results,
          movieFound: true,
          queryMovie: '',
         }))
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        Axios 
        .get(`http://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=us&category=entertainment&apiKey=4a6b942733e54342962e5df94feb48aa`)
        .then(response => response.data)
        .then(newsdata => this.setState({ newsdata }));
        console.log('console inside componentwillmount', this.state.newsdata)
      }

      render() {

        return (
          <div className="container">
            <div className="headerbodycontainer">
              <h2>App with 2 APIs</h2>
              <h4>Movie Finder and Entertainment News</h4>
            </div>
              <div className="row">
                <div className="col-6">
                  <div className="headerbodycardcontainer">
                    <div className="card-header">Movie Finder</div>
                    <div className="card-body">
                      <input name="queryMovie" onChange={this.handleInputChange} placeholder="Enter Movie" value={this.state.queryMovie}></input>
                      <button onClick={this.searchMovie}>Search Movie</button>
                    </div> 
                    <div className="container">
                      <MovieView 
                        results={this.state.results}
                        movieFound={this.state.movieFound}
                    /></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div className="col-6">
                  <div className="headerbodycontainer">
                    <div className="card-header">ENTERTAINMENT NEWS</div>
                      {/* {
                      this.state.newsdata.map(article => (
                        <NewsView
                          title={article.title}
                          description={article.description}
                          url={article.url}
                          />
                      ))
                    }   */}
                    <div className="card-body"></div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;

    **MovieView component:**
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import Movie from './movie'

    const MovieView = (props) => {
        console.log(props.movieFound, 'props passed to movieview')
        console.log(props.results.results, 'results inside movieview')
        if (props.movieFound == true && props.results.results.length>0) {
            return (<div><Movie movieData={props.results}/></div>)
        } else {
            return <div>HELLO WORLD</div>
        }
    }

    export default MovieView;

    **Movie component:**
    import React from 'react';

    const Movie = (props) => {
        console.log(props, 'inside movie comp')
        console.log(props.results, 'inside props results')
        props.results.map((movie) => {
        return <div>
            <ul>
                <li>Movie title: {movie.original_title}</li>
                <li>Overview: {movie.overview}</li>
                <li>Homepage: {movie.homepage}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        })
    }


    export default Movie;
```

So right now I get to the Movie component but I get an error which indicates that I'm currently not returning anything. Any help or feedback will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: you could have shared your code in the codepen or codesandbox

Comment: here is the same code in sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-dream-e0ys5

Comment: True, sorry about that... first time posting. will keep it in mind for next time!

Answer (score 0):

Your `Movie` component needs to return valid JSX, i.e. the array of elements or null.

```
const Movie = (props) => {
  console.log(props, 'inside movie comp');
  console.log(props.results, 'inside props results');

  return props.results.map((movie) => { // return the mapped array of movies
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>Movie title: {movie.original_title}</li>
          <li>Overview: {movie.overview}</li>
          <li>Homepage: {movie.homepage}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  })
}
```

`MovieView` also includes an invalid reference to `results`. `props.results` versus `props.results.results`.

```
const MovieView = (props) => {
    console.log(props.movieFound, 'props passed to movieview')
    console.log(props.results, 'results inside movieview')
    if (props.movieFound && props.results.length) {
        return (<div><Movie movieData={props.results}/></div>)
    } else {
        return <div>HELLO WORLD</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Drew... how would i do that?

Comment: oh thanks! I'll fix that. Would it be better to use map or foreach or even a for loop?

Comment: @Barbs_California that depends on the specific use-case, but `array::map` is typically used to render an array into JSX children components. (I assume this is what you're asking about) You are mapping the array of movie objects to an array of JSX elements.